# How to refresh in Hibernate bypassing the cache 1st level

Tags: java, database, spring, hibernate, jpa

Could someone explain me why my parent's doesn't have the child populated even though I'm refreshing the entity ?

I've included here the parentDao2Test class as well as the ParentService, ChildService, DBChild and DBParent. The parentDAO and childDao are basic simple. The parentDao2Test is run through a SpringJUnit4ClassRunner junit runner.

```
public class ParentDao2Test {
    @Autowired private ParentService parentService;
    @Test
    public void testCRUD() {
        DBParent parent = parentService.createParent();
        assertTrue(parent.getId() > 0);
        parent = parentService.createChildForParent(parent.getId());
        assertTrue(parent.getChilds().size() > 0);
    }
 }

public class ParentService{
    @Autowired ParentDao parentDao;
    @Autowired ChildService childService;

    @Transactional(propagation=Propagation.REQUIRES_NEW) 
    public DBParent createParent() {
        DBParent parent = new DBParent();
        parentDao.persist(parent);
        return parent;
    }

    @Transactional(propagation=Propagation.REQUIRES_NEW) 
    public DBParent createChildForParent(long parentId) {
        DBParent parent = parentDao.findById(parentId);
        childService.createChildForParent(parentId);

        HashMap<String, Object> props = new HashMap<String, Object>();
        props.put("org.hibernate.cacheMode", CacheMode.IGNORE);
        parentDao.refresh(parent);
        return parent;
    }
}

public class ChildService {
    @Autowired ChildDao childDao;
    @Autowired ParentDao parentDao;

    @Transactional(propagation=Propagation.REQUIRES_NEW) 
    public DBChild createChildForParent(long parentId) {
        DBParent parent = parentDao.findById(parentId);
        DBChild child = new DBChild();
        child.setName("Name");
        childDao.persist(child);
        parent.addChild(child);
        parentDao.persist(parent);
        parentDao.flush();
        return child;
    }
}

@Entity
@Table(name = "Parent")
public class DBParent {
    @Id
    @Column(name="id")
    @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.AUTO) 
    private long id;

    @OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.EAGER, cascade = {CascadeType.ALL}, orphanRemoval=true)
    @JoinColumn(name = "childs", nullable=true)
    private Set<DBChild> childs = new HashSet<DBChild>();

    public DBParent() {
        super();
    }
}

@Entity
@Table(name = "child")
public class DBChild {
    @Id
    @Column(name="id")
    @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.AUTO) 
    private long id;

    @Column(name="name", nullable = false, length=1024)
    private String name;

    public DBChild() {
        super();
    }
}
```

Comment: Try using merge on the parent instead of persist, and check that the child tables "childs" field is populated in the database after the child entity is inserted.

Answer (score 0):

After a full day of deep debugging, I finally found the problem of my issue.

I'm seeing this behavior because my transaction is configured in REPEATABLE_READ (which is the default). This means that Spring guarantees that two reads of the same data within the same transaction will always return the same result. As the isolation level takes precedence on my cache eviction or entity refresh, even though I refresh or evict the parent entity, this had no effect.

There is a ways to work around this behavior:
Declare your transaction isolation level to READ_UNCOMMITTED or READ_COMMITTED. You might run into the famous "Standard JPA does not support custom isolation levels" exception if you are using a standard dialect. In which case you can apply the following workaround: 
spring 3.3:http://amitstechblog.wordpress.com/2011/05/31/supporting-custom-isolation-levels-with-jpa/
spring 3.2:http://shahzad-mughal.blogspot.com/2012/04/spring-jpa-hibernate-support-for-custom.html

To make my code to work I had to change the following method:

```
@Transactional(propagation=Propagation.REQUIRES_NEW, isolation=Isolation.READ_COMMITTED) 
public DBParent createChildForParent(long parentId) {
    DBParent parent = parentDao.findById(parentId);
    childService.createChildForParent(parentId);

    parentDao.getSession().evict(parent);
    parent = parentDao.findById(parentId);
    return parent;
}
```